# Como seleccionar el texto artistico de la seleccion actual en VBA Corel?

Tags: vba

Uso corel Draw y quiero crear un macro que permita de la seleccion actual hacer una copia justo debajo, despues en esa copia coger unicamente el texto y cambiarlo por cualquier otro texto, por ejemplo "nuevo texto".
Cree mi codigo entre experimentos y con tutoriales por ahi, el codigo actual no me funciona porque dice que la  linea "Set TextSelection = OrigSelection.CreateSelectionFromType(cdrArtisticTextShape)" es un objeto que no admite esta propiedad o metodo, asumo que el programa no entiende que es lo que necesito seleccionar.

> Lo que creo que necesito es una linea de codigo que permita de la
> seleccion de la copia coger unicamente el texto y luego aplicarle la
> linea que cambia el texto.

Te agradezco si me puedes ayudar ;)

Aqui el codigo:

```
Sub CambiarTexto()
    ' Declara dos variables: "OrigSelection" y "dup1"
    Dim OrigSelection As ShapeRange
    Set OrigSelection = ActiveSelectionRange
    Dim dup1 As ShapeRange
    Set dup1 = OrigSelection.Duplicate
    Dim TextSelection As ShapeRange

' Mueve la copia de la selección actual de formas (dup1) 0 unidades a la izquierda y la altura de la selección original hacia arriba
    dup1.Move 0#, -0.393701

' Crea una nueva selección de formas que incluye solo las formas de texto de la copia de la selección

    Set TextSelection = OrigSelection.CreateSelectionFromType(cdrArtisticTextShape)
' Cambia el contenido del texto de la primera forma de texto en la copia de la selección
dup1.Shapes(0).Text.Story.String = "Nuevo texto"
End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, crees que mi pregunta esta mal formulada?